# XMLHttpRequest Catch Empty XML Response with Status 200

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest, amazon-product-api

I have a script that queries a local PHP file by creating an XMLHttpRequest. Sometimes the PHP file returns nothing and thus an error is thrown saying:

```
XML Parsing Error: no root element found
Location: <URL of page>
Line Number 1, Column 1:
^
```

How can I catch this error so I can display a message saying something like, "No Results"?

This may be irrelevant for this question, but extra information probably won't hurt. I am using the Amazon Product Advertising API, and I only get this error when there are spaces in the keywords, even though I `urlencode` the keywords properly. It works fine if I only have one word, but not if there are multiple for some reason. Not quite sure what the issue is there, but I still would like to be able to catch these errors in a user friendly way.

Comment: Try to get the actual response of your request to see what happens.

Comment: Use the `onerror` method and pass a callback function.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onerror

Comment: Mind that if there is an error, you should send an error status, not 200, which implies that everything is OK.